# How I reached index.mapping.total_fields.limit?

Tags: elasticsearch, kotlin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am loading data to Elasticsearch and I've got `index.mapping.total_fields.limit`. I totally don't understand why I've got this error, my class which I am loading to ES looks like:

```
@Document(type = "article", indexName = "data")
data class Product(
        @Id
        val id: String? = null,
        val category: String,
        val name: String,
        val imagesUrls: List<String>,
        val parameters: Map<String, List<String>>?
)
```

I added already around 3k of products, after that I got this error. Can you explain to me, why I got this? I thought I had only 5 fields in my Product class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour comes from the fact that you don't specify how the *parameters* property should be stored. Let's assume, that in one entity, paraneters is a map from "foo" to some data. This leads to the following mappings to be created (only showing the relevant part):

```
{
  "article": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "parameters": {
          "properties": {
            "foo": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If the next entity had `parameters` from *bar* to something, a new mapping entry for "bar" is created. And once the number of keys in your map exceeds the limit, you get that error.

**Edit 03.08.2020:**

You could create a class `Parameter`:

```
data class Parameter(
    val key: String,
    val values: List<String>
)
```

and change the corresponding property in the `Product` class to

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
val parameters: List<Parameter>
```

You lose the unique-key guarantee that the `Map` has and would need to check this somewhere in your code.

Personally, I would have in my application a domain layer where I would use a `Map` and a persistence layer where I use the specific version needed to store the data - here with a `List`.  And when converting data from domain to persistence layer and back, I would make this transformation.

Comment: How can I fix that? How can I specify the way to store parameters?

Comment: I added more info to my answer